# Video recording/playback/storage for website

Tags: html, video, amazon-s3, webrtc

I would like to implement video recording/playback/storage capability for my website. I'm done a bit of research, for HTML5 recording, there is RecordRTC which is based on WebRTC. For playback there's video.js. I want to be able to store them on s3 but I haven't figured out how.

1) Is this the best way to do it without paying for cloud based commercial ones such as ziggeo, nimbb and pipe?

2) are there any alternatives that i should look into?

3) how does storage work after recording using RecordRTC and uploading to s3? Do i need to do any sort of compression?
Any help would be great! Really appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Video recording is the future of all websites in our eyes - and by our I mean here at Ziggeo (full disclosure, I work at Ziggeo :) ).

In regards to recording there are many ways to do it and it is up to you to go with a specific one or implement all of them, so you could do it through Flash, WebRTC (https://webrtc.org/), or ORTC (https://ortc.org/).

We are currently offering you to record using WebRTC plus fallback with Flash and are working on implementing ORTC as well.

Now as mentioned above, there are many ways to do it and it is up to you, however it is up to your end users also since they might not be able to record over flash due to company policy or your website is on HTTP so you can not use WebRTC, etc.

With your own implementation you need to run the numbers and combine it all together (and work on keeping it up and running), while here at Ziggeo we do that for you and keep improving our SDKs and features.

Further more we also allow you to push the videos to [S3 buckets, FTP](https://ziggeo.com/features/push-service), [YouTube](https://ziggeo.com/features/youtube-integration) and [Facebook](https://ziggeo.com/features/facebook-integration) - soon to DropBox as well.

So if you are like us, you will probably like to go down the road of do it yourself. If you however want to have time to work on your website, apps, and other things and just have the video, I do suggest using some service.

In regards to compression. It is good to mention that we do transcoding of all videos that are uploaded to our servers (You can see more here: https://ziggeo.com/features/transcoding). There is an original video that is kept and next to it the transcoded video (which can have watermark or some effects, etc. while it does not need to).

In general you want to 'standardize' the uploaded videos since different browsers will give you different video data containers and this would give you the upper hand so that it is easier to make adjustments to them later on for preview depending on the browser that is used.

To summarize:

1) - This depends on what kind of recording/playback and storage you need. If it is professional then using a service such as Ziggeo will help you focus on the important part of your service - like website design, functionality and similar, while if it is for fun and play you still have a free plan on Ziggeo, or you could get your sleeves up and do some codding :)

2) - I would personally look into WebRTC and ORTC if I was making implementation myself to see which one I would need more (or would be easier for me to implement). Once you find the one that you like, they usually offer some suggestions on their forums with what works best for them. (Be prepared however to need flash implementation at some point as well if it is business related setup)

3) It is best to standardize what you store in terms of resolution, video data containers and similar and often it is good to keep the original videos as well, so that you can always re-encode them if that is needed (which can happen in early stages of development).